# I am creating simple web application using playframework 2.5.4 UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error

Tags: playframework

I have project structure as below as per [Migration Document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25)  and [New application Document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication) for playframework 2.5.4.

#### plugins.sbt with:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

 // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

#### build.sbt with:

```
name := """ProjectNameWebProxy"""

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

**But following dependencies not found**

```
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 :: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.5.4: not found
 :: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.5.4: not found
 :: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.10;2.5.4: not found
 :: com.typesafe.play#play-logback_2.10;2.5.4: not found
 :: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.5.4: not found
 :: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.10;2.5.4: not found
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Kindly help me to get stared with demo project on web proxy.

Answer (score 7):

In every unresolved dependency:

```
:: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.5.4: not found
```

2.10 is Scala version and 2.5.4 is PlayFramework version. But **PlayFramework 2.5.4 does not support Scala 2.10**. The problem is solved by setting scala version in *built.sbt*:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Now it will work with:

```
com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.11;2.5.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting scala version in your build.sbt file.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Migration guide says: "Play 2.3 and 2.4 supported both Scala 2.10 and 2.11. Play 2.5 has dropped support for Scala 2.10 and now only supports Scala 2.11."

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience 
i face lot of issues while migrating 2.4 to 2.5

so i take a latest templet of play-java

to take latest

```
open command prompt and go to your project directory and
type 
activator new yourProjectName
then
select 5th option
```

then it completed to install latest templet of play-java
if you want to convert it in eclipse
type

```
activator eclipse
```